# Add on or App Script to customize Google form Confirmation Page onFormSubmit or onOpen | Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've been trying to search for ways via app script and add-ons that allow us to customize a google form's confirmation page once the user clicks on the submit button. So far, resources have been mentioned that this isn't possible, but the latest reference I saw was in 2014, so not sure if there were any updates already.

I'm good if it's an add-on as well, but I do prefer script so that I can learn and avoid paying.

Alternatively, is it possible to redirect a user to a custom URL based on his/her response once s/he clicks on submit?

Hoping for your guidance on this. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can include a link in the confirmation message, but that requires that the user clicks the link. Try [Formfacade](https://formfacade.com/website/resource/thank-you-pages-confirmation-messages.html) (subscription based) or ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Maybe Google Chat is the answer you've been looking for

I believe that it is impossible because we have no access to the that instance of the form.  Once the form is submitted we could send the user any email but I think that's about it.

However according to my research you could use google apps script to set up an interactive [chat message](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/12007046?hl=en).  Here's some addition information for setting up a webhook for [Google Chat](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks).  Let me know if you have any success with this suggestion.